# Extract child tags as well as untagged text using beautiful soup 4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="parent">
 <h1>  Jeff Bezos </h1>
 CEO and Founder, Amazon
 <h2> Elon musk <h2>
 <p> CEO of SpaceX <p>
 <p> CEO of <a>Tesla<a> <p>
</div>
```

So essentially I need to loop over all the children of parent, and I was previously using this code

> parent.find_all(recursive=False):

But now I run into an issue where I have pages with untagged text, so "CEO and Founder, Amazon" in this example. The children tags can have deep levels of nesting, but I need to loop over all of the items 1 level down, including untagged text. There is no structure or pattern here that I can make use of, the untagged text is at random places within the html

My expected output:

```
["<h1>  Jeff Bezos </h1>", 
 "CEO and Founder, Amazon", 
 "<h2> Elon musk <h2>",
 "<p> CEO of SpaceX <p>",
 "<p> CEO of <a>Tesla<a> <p>"]
```

Where the lines with tags remain bs4 objects, but the string is extracted as a navigablestring or just the text

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="parent">
 <h1>  Jeff Bezos </h1>
 CEO and Founder, Amazon
 <h2> Elon musk <h2>
 <p> CEO of SpaceX <p>
 <p> CEO of <a>Tesla<a> <p>
</div>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(list(soup.select_one('.parent').stripped_strings))
```

Output:

```
['Jeff Bezos', 'CEO and Founder, Amazon', 'Elon musk', 'CEO of SpaceX', 'CEO of', 'Tesla']
```

Comment: I need to keep the tags of the things with tags, I updated the OP with what I am looking for.

Comment: @Adamater something like `print(soup.select_one('.parent'))` ?

Comment: @Adamater [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)